# Robustness of Tjur's R^2 for Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, experiment-design, r-squared

I'm designing an experiment and plan to use [Tjur's ${R}^2$](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tast.2009.08210), denoted $D$, to evaluate some logistic regressions. He defines the value in these three equivalent ways:

1. $D = \bar{\hat\pi_1} - \bar{\hat\pi_0}$ where $\bar{\hat\pi_1}$ and $\bar{\hat\pi_0}$ denote the averages of fitted values (predicted probabilities) for successes and failure respectively
2. $D = \frac{1}{2}\left(R^2_{mod}R^2_{res}\right)$
3. $D = \sqrt{R^2_{mod}R^2_{cor}}$

Let's say I want to test the effect of two features ($F_1$ and $F_2$) on some dependent variable. I run an experiment for $F_1$ on Monday and an experiment for $F_2$ on Tuesday. I construct a Logistic Regression for both experiments and calculate Tjur's $R^2$ value for both regressions.

Let's say I also know that the dependent variable is affected by the day of the week, but the relationship is unknown. **Does this day of week affect prevent me from comparing $R^2$ values between experiments or does the construction of the value make it robust to underlying differences in probability?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tjur's is purely an index of discrimination. But because your experimental conditions are confounded with the day of week, no statistical technique can bypass this underlying flaw, unless you can provide some information to the modeling process to adjust for this confounding.